# XE3 Build configuration break Grid RowSelect when using "Release" build

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-xe3, search-path

I have found a problem in XE3 that I am not sure is of my own making, i made a small app. The whole code being

```
unit xe3testrelease;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Data.DB,
  IBODataset, IB_Components, IB_Access;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IBOTransaction1: TIBOTransaction;
    IBODatabaseMain: TIBODatabase;
    IBOQuery1: TIBOQuery;
    DataSourceQuery: TDataSource;
    IBOTransactionQuery: TIBOTransaction;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

=========================================

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 509
  ClientWidth = 905
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 40
    Top = 128
    Width = 817
    Height = 353
    DataSource = DataSourceQuery
    Options = [dgTitles, dgIndicator, dgColumnResize, dgColLines, dgRowLines, dgTabs, dgRowSelect, dgConfirmDelete, dgCancelOnExit, dgMultiSelect, dgTitleClick, dgTitleHotTrack]
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object IBOTransaction1: TIBOTransaction
    IB_Connection = IBODatabaseMain
    Isolation = tiCommitted
    Left = 272
    Top = 16
  end
  object IBODatabaseMain: TIBODatabase
    CacheStatementHandles = False
    LoginCaption = 'MASTER COMPANY DATABASE'
    LoginPrompt = True
    SQLDialect = 3
    DatabaseName = 'DANTMFG_1_1'
    Params.Strings = (
      'USER NAME=SYSDBA'
      'PATH=D:\data\OCEAN01.fdb')
    Isolation = tiCommitted
    DriverName = ''
    Left = 54
    Top = 16
    SavedPassword = '.JuMbLe.01.432B0639073E0E4B49'
  end
  object IBOQuery1: TIBOQuery
    Active = True
    DatabaseName = 'DANTMFG_1_1'
    IB_Connection = IBODatabaseMain
    IB_Transaction = IBOTransactionQuery
    PreparedEdits = True
    PreparedInserts = False
    ReadOnly = True
    RecordCountAccurate = True
    SQL.Strings = (
      'select * from part')
    FieldOptions = []
    Left = 48
    Top = 72
  end
  object DataSourceQuery: TDataSource
    DataSet = IBOQuery1
    Left = 152
    Top = 72
  end
  object IBOTransactionQuery: TIBOTransaction
    IB_Connection = IBODatabaseMain
    ReadOnly = True
    Isolation = tiCommitted
    Left = 272
    Top = 72
  end
```

## end

I set both grid options dgmultiselect and dgrowselect to true.

If i compile the project using debug, the grid shows a complete blue line for each selected line and allows multiple selected lines highlighted in blue...This works.

But if I build using the "Release" build, the program acts very strangely , where the select only outlines the row in blue, and the multiselect only returns one line as the selected row count..
Obviously something in the "Release" build is different has broken.

I have checked all the paths until i am blue in the face but i cannot see whats happening.

All the paths in both Release and Debug look the same, Can anyone give me a clue as to where i might look.

If i build a few of my clients applications they all break in strange ways if compiled in XE3 using the Release build.

I cant see how to create a reproduce-able example that will break on another machine as I am convinced it is some setting in my Build configuration that is causing this behavior.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information, because nothing you've provided allows reproducing the problem. Can you [edit] to provide your .dfm in text format? (Right-click, view as text, copy and paste here, format as code.) Also, as a note: Signatures are not appropriate here. You have an entire user profile where you can tell people about yourself if you so choose; it's available by clicking your user name and editing your profile. The [help] pages have more details if you need them.

Comment: Hi Ken, I have supplied the Dfm, can i get a copy of the of the compilation parameters somehow ? I am sure the problem is in the difference between DEBUG and RELEASE builds. i have added the compile data from the messages panel if it helps

Comment: I have made a new app using the Tib components in Delphi XE3 and still see the same problem, i have put a copy at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49653505/XE3ReleaseTest.zip